# nifty_generators gem appears installed but still can't use generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.0 in WinXP. I ran `gem install nifty-generators` from inside a new project directory. It said the gem, version 0.4.2, was successfully installed but there was an error installing ri and rdoc, so I ran the same command again but with the --no-ri --no-rdoc switches. Now it appears nifty_generators is installed with no errors, and it shows up in my `gem list`, but when I run `rails g nifty:layout` it says the nifty:layout generator wasn't found.  `rails g nifty_layout` also doesn't work. Anyone has ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: Outputs as requested:

```
C:\Documents\Prgm>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

I'm running XP, so don't have `which`, but ruby.exe is in `C:\Ruby192\bin`.

```
C:\Documents\Prgm>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby192/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Documents and Settings/Linh/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

C:\Prgm\Survey_Manager>rails generate
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  mailer
  migration
  model
  observer
  performance_test
  plugin
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  session_migration
  stylesheets
```

Also, `rails g` is shorthand for `rails generate` in Rails 3. See e.g. here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have almost the same configuration as you, @Anita (win XP, rails 3 and ruby 1.9.3), and `rails g nifty:layout` works pretty well for me.

Make sure that you're running `rails g` command from the root directory of your app (i.e. from the directory where `Gemfile` is located). Also, make sure that your `Gemfile` contains this line: `gem 'nifty-generators'`.

Comment: Sweet! I manually added `gem 'nifty-generators'` to the Gemfile, and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the output of the following commands so we could try and help you:

- ruby -v
- which ruby
- gem env
- rails generate

Also, note that `rails g nifty_layout` should not work as it's not the right syntax.

---

Everything seems alright as far as I can see. would you be able to install another gem with a generator, such as paperclip and see if it's add to your generator list. as well could it be possible that you have more than one version of rails/ruby installed ?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the [nifty generators github page](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators).

> ## Rails 3
>
> To use Nifty Generators with Rails 3
>   you will need to include it in your
>   Gemfile.
>
> ```
> gem "nifty-generators"
> ```
>
> The generators use a colon as the
>   separator instead of an underscore.
>
> ```
> rails g nifty:layout
> ```
>
> The Rails 3 support is still in early
>   development, please [report any
>   issues](http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/issues)
>   you find.

Comment: Read that doc. `gem "nifty-generators"` returns "command not found". `rails g nifty:layout` returns same error as `rails g nifty_layout`.

Comment: Next time, you should put that it returns "command not found", since the docs are telling you to do that, and it isn't working.